# Dice Score for semantic segmentation when some of labels has all zeros

Tags: semantic-segmentation

I am calculating Dice Score for binary segmentation case, in some of my ground truths there is no label, i.e. it has all zeros. So when I use a different batch size for inference I am getting different results, especially worst for batch size=1, I came to know the reason as shown in the following figure: It averages all the cases even when the TP=0:
[results descriptions][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHj3o.png

What is the logical solution, and how do the experts deal with this problem, one possible solution can be: Calculate Dice Score only for those predictions for which ground truth>0
Is it the right approach to publish the results? I didn't see any paper mentioning this issue:
Any link to the published work which dealt with this problem will be appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: One solution I've come across is to use a large smoothing factor... for instance 100